# ¿Como ordernar un arreglo de registro de tipo String usando Shell Sort?

Tags: java, c#, ordenamiento, c#-8.0

Estoy usando Shell Sort para ordenar un registro de estudiante por su carnet,
pero su carnet es ingresado mediante string, para hacer la comparacion
hago un string compare, pero a la hora de visualizar solo me ordena los
2 ultimos estudianete, dejandome los demas sin ordenar.

```
    public void ShellSort(Registro[]reg)
    {
        int salto = reg.Length / 2;
        int j=0;
        Registro auxiliar = new Registro();

        if (reg.Length!=0)
        {
            while (salto>0)
            {
                for (int i = salto; i < reg.Length; i++)
                {
                    j = i - salto;
                    auxiliar = reg[i];

                    int comp = string.Compare(auxiliar.carnet, reg[j].carnet);

                    while ((j>=0) && (comp==-1)) //auxiliar<reg[j]
                    {
                        reg[j + salto] = reg[j];
                        j = j - salto;
                    }

                    reg[j + salto] = auxiliar;
                }
                salto = salto / 2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Arreglo ordenado exitosamente...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n No hay datos que ordenar");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto son los datos de salida, y son los datos que no se ordenan, para ordenarlo tengo que estar manando a llamar varias veces al metodo ShellSort.

Comment: puede colocar los datos que estan entrando, como quedan ordenados y como deberían quedar.

Comment: en esta pagina encuentra los algoritmos, compare el suyo con el que proponen aca https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shellsort/, yo verificare por mi cuenta y si encuentro algo le comento.

Comment: muchas gracias, pero ya habia visto esa pagina y probado el metodo que sale ahí, el problema que presento es que cuando lo modifico para datos de tipo string, el ordenamiento no se hace correctamente, tal vez me falta algo, o solo el string.Compare no sea suficiente?.